# Find out current working directory of a running process?

Tags: shell, command-line, process, cwd

What command(s) can one use to find out the current working directory (CWD) of a running process? These would be commands you could use externally from the process.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

There are 3 methods that I'm aware of:

#### pwdx

```
$ pwdx <PID>
```

#### lsof

```
$ lsof -p <PID> | grep cwd
```

#### /proc

```
$ readlink -e /proc/<PID>/cwd
```

#### Examples

Say we have this process.

```
$ pgrep nautilus
12136
```

Then if we use `pwdx`:

```
$ pwdx 12136
12136: /home/saml
```

Or you can use `lsof`:

```
$ lsof -p 12136 | grep cwd
nautilus 12136 saml  cwd    DIR              253,2    32768  10354689 /home/saml
```

Or you can poke directly into the `/proc`:

```
$ readlink -e /proc/12136/cwd/
/home/saml
```

Comment: I would say /proc is canonical, with lsof being useful, but pwdx is cool.

Comment: Not all Unices have `/proc`.

Comment: A similar but different question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173868/find-out-to-which-directory-a-process-is-writing

Comment: `pwdx` works for me.

Comment: Here is a simple way (from slm's answer) pwdx `pgrep <process-name>`

Comment: In Ubuntu Server 18.04 the above commands require `root` privileges. At least in OpenBSD, you can see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658496/93174) to my U&L question.

Comment: @slm Can you also use `ps -ef | grep pid`?

Answer (score 32):

I assume that you have the process ID in `pid`. Most methods on most systems will require that the shell you're doing this from is running as the same user as the target process (or root).

On Linux and Solaris and perhaps some other System V unices:

```
cd /proc/$pid/cwd && pwd
```

On Linux (except embedded systems where `readlink` is not available) but not Solaris:

```
readlink /proc/$pid/cwd
```

On just about any unix variant, you can use [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof). Beware that if there is a newline, it will be printed as `\n` (indistinguishable from backslash followed by `n`). If you feel lucky, you can use the second form, which silently chokes on all whitespace in the directory name.

```
lsof -a -Fn -p $pid -d cwd | sed -e '1d' -e '2s/^n/'
lsof -p $pid | awk '$4=="cwd" {print $9}'
```

---

Bonus: if you need to cause a process to change its current directory, you can do it with a debugger. This is useful for example to move a long-running program that doesn't care about its current directory out of a directory that you want to remove. Not all programs appreciate having their current directory changed under their feet — for example a shell is likely to crash.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Use gdb to change the working directory of a process from outside.
# This could be generalized to a lot of other things.

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 PID DIR"
  exit 120
fi
case "$1" in
  *[!0-9]*) echo 1>&2 "Invalid pid \`$1'"; exit 3;;
esac
case "$2" in
  *[\\\"]*)
    echo 1>&2 "Unsupported character in directory name, sorry."
    exit 3;;
esac

gdb -n -pid "$1" -batch -x /dev/stdin <<EOF
call chdir("$2")
detach
quit
EOF
```

Comment: Nice touch adding the details in about moving. Good little nugget to add to the site!

Comment: Can you comment at all on the ubiquity of `pwdx` on other Unixes?

Comment: On OpenBSD, at least, lsof only reports the mount point of the process's CWD.

Comment: @slm `pwdx` is present on Solaris since the 20th century, Linux since the mid-2000s (imitating Solaris, says the man page). Not present on any other unix AFAIK.

Comment: @kurtm - any better method on BSD? Also is `pwdx` there?

Comment: @slm Not that I found so far.  `pwdx` is not on there, and unless it's part of a package, I don't see a package for it.  `fuser` is like lsof but it only takes a file or mount point and tell you which processes have it open (or have files open on that filesystem).  It's an interesting blind spot.

Comment: @slm on FreeBSD you can view current directory using [procstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procstat&apropos=0&sektion=1): `procstat -f PID` and look for cwd.

Answer (score 9):

If your system has `/proc`, you can always do:

```
readlink -e /proc/$$/cwd
```

If you want to find out the CWD from a different process than the one you're interested in, you obviously need to replace `$$` with the PID of your process of interest.

Answer (score 4):

For macOS: If you know the PID and want to get the exact file/directory (no other information) use:

```bsh
lsof -a -p 1234 -d cwd -F n | tail -1 | cut -c2-
```

`-a`: Tell lsof to join using AND instead of OR for the `-p` and `-d` options below
`-p`: pass in process id (pid) 1234
`-d`: only include the file descriptor, cwd
`-F`: Specify the fields to output (choose from the list of characters [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html#OUTPUT_FOR_OTHER_PROGRAMS))

The `n` character passed to `-F` option outputs 3 things separated by newlines. We only want the last one (the current working directory). We pipe the output into `tail` to get the last line then pipe it into `cut` to trim the first character.

Comment: Note that you still need to decode that output as `lsof` encodes control character, backslash and the bytes of some non-ASCII characters using `\xHH`, `\b`, `\n`, `\\ ` etc notation.

Answer (score 1):

Based @Gilles answer..

if you know [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of your process.. for **Mac OSX** and **Linux** use:

```
lsof -p PID | awk '$4=="cwd" {print $9}'
```

to get working dir of process..

Comment: `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() tracefs file system /sys/kernel/debug/tracing Output information may be incomplete.` Anyone else get this?

Comment: @SridharSarnobat, you can always add the `-w` options to suppress those warnings.

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD you can use:

```
procstat -f <PID> | grep cwd
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a more "visual" solution (useful if you want to check a lot of processes, but still works from the terminal):

1. use the command `htop` (might need to be installed first),
2. select process with up-down arrows,
3. press <kbd>e</kbd> to show the process environment,
4. press <kbd>F4</kbd> and filter for `PWD`.

(If To stop the processes change place all the time, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.)

Comment: See  `lsof -d cwd` to see the cwd of more than one process.

Comment: Note that that shows the `$PWD` environment variable in the environment the process received in the last execve() system call it performed which is not guaranteed to be the same as the current working directory of the process.