# Find out to which directory a process is writing?

Tags: process, open-files

This question is NOT a duplicate of this question [Find out current working directory of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process), because **the writing directory can be different from the working directory.**

For example, I start two processes by running `my_script.sh` in ~/ twice (one right after another).

In `my_script.sh`, I have made it to write the output to a folder whose name is a time stamp. Hence, despite the same working directory, the two processes actually write into different directories, say `~/1212_000001/` and `~/1212_000003/`. (the 1st process starts at 00:00:01 on Dec. 12 and the 2nd starts 2 seconds later)

The solution in the question linked returns me the same result `~/` for the two processes and thus fail my purpose.

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on how the script is writing:

- If directly by redirection (i.e. `my_script.sh > ~/1212_000001/some_file`), you can use `lsof -p <script-pid>` and you'll see the open file on your output directory
- Else, the output of `ps axjf`' will show you the pid dependencies of sub-processes launched by your script, which may give you the information immediately in command arguments or allow you to play `lsof -p <sub-process-pid>` on sub-processes.

Of course, if this occurs in a very short time, this method will not apply.

You can also make use of 'strace' command and look for "open" calls.

Comment: Thanks sir. It's not by redirection. It is an external C program that writes to directory. So I presume the external C program has another PID, right?