# What does pwd output?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Does the command `pwd` in a shell script output the directory the shell script is in?

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Yes, that is the full name of the command, but what does it return exactly? *At the start of a script it is the pwd of the shell that is calling the script, not the directory that contains the script!*

Comment: No, I aready understand what you mean, but you seem to be mistakenly using the word "shell" and "shell script" synonymously. I think you meant "shell script" in your last comment. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Read my answer. May be of help.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a program's _output_ (what it prints to stdout and stderr) and its _return value_ (on most systems, effectively an eight-bit unsigned integer derived from what the program's `main` function returned, or what it passed to `exit()`). `pwd` _prints_ its working directory (if possible); it [_returns_](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) zero if it succeeded and nonzero if it failed.

Comment: I seems you'd like to know the directory containing the script. In that case you'd need to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630372/determine-the-path-of-the-executing-bash-script) or the ones it links to.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange. You appear to have asked a question with a Yes/No answer, leading others to guess what you really want to know. A better question for this site might have been *"What does pwd return when called from inside a shell script?"* or *"When a shell script is running, how can it find the directory containing the script?"*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are three independent "directories" at play here:

1. your current shell's current working directory,
2. the shell script's current working directory, and
3. the directory containing the shell script.

To demonstrate that they are independent, you can write a shell script, saved to /tmp/pwd.sh, containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
pwd
cd /var 
pwd
```

You can then change your pwd (#1 above) to /:

```
cd /
```

and execute the script:

```
/tmp/pwd.sh
```

which starts off by demonstrating your existing pwd (#1), then changes it to /var and shows it again (#2). Neither of those `pwd`'s were "/tmp", the directory that contains /tmp/pwd.sh (#3).

Comment: It will not necessarily display the directory that *contains* the shell script, if that's causing confusion.

Comment: Oh, right. The shell script can change `pwd`. I did not know that. But your answer is formulated a little confusingly. I would rewrite it...

Comment: And the answer is actually no, after all, because I indeed **did** mean the directory that contains the shell script.

Comment: No, the edit does not help. It still sounds like you are talking about the directory that contains the shell script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35626/discussion-between-mkdrive2-and-jeff-schaller).

Comment: It's worth noting that programs (including scripts; scripts are programs) inherit their working directories from their parents. A process can change its own working directory, but that won't affect its parent's. `cd` and commands like it work because they are _builtins_ that run within the shell, rather than external programs in their own right.

Answer (score 7):

### Present (or Current) Working Directory

> Does the command pwd in a shell script return the directory the shell script is in?

No.

Firstly, by definition, no shell script or shell command returns anything other than a numeric exit status between 0 - 255. That's axiomatic, but not generally not what people mean when they ask these types of questions.

Secondly, `pwd` is both a [Bourne shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) and a standard system binary. Either one **prints** the logical or physical *current working directory*, which is generally:

1. Your location in the directory structure when you call a script or binary.
2. Your current location after changing the working directory with *cd* or other utilities and builtins that modify the current working directory such as pushd or popd.

If you want the directory of the current script, use the `dirname` utility as described in the final section below.

### Quick Test of `pwd`

As a quick test to see what *pwd* really prints, you can run the following:

```
# Create a shell script containing pwd.
cat <<-EOF > /tmp/test_pwd.sh
#!/bin/sh

pwd
EOF

# Make the script executable.
chmod 755 /tmp/test_pwd.sh

# Go somewhere on the filesystem, and call the test script.
cd /etc
/tmp/test_pwd.sh
```

This will print `/etc`, not `/tmp`, because your current working directory is currently `/etc`. This is the expected behavior.

### Getting the Directory Containing a Script

You're probably asking this question because you want to find the directory of the current script. In the general case, the following is the quick-and-dirty solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $(dirname "$0")
```

This works because `$0` generally contains the pathname used to invoke the script being executed, and the shell expansion uses the `dirname` utility to return the path excluding the filename portion. You can do something similar, but less portably, with the Bash parameter expansion `"${0%/*}"`.

This is all a vast over-simplification, of course. Please read the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) (especially the sections on positional parameters, special parameters, and *BASH_SOURCE*) and the man pages for `readlink` and `realpath` to get a fuller understanding of what the edge cases are, of which there are several.

However, in day-to-day scripting, the directory component of `$0` is sufficient to tell you what you want to know. If you are doing something complicated enough where `$0` doesn't hold the information you actually need, and you require more complicated constructs like:

```
echo $(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")
```

then you're probably making your life more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you're describing what `pwd` _prints_, not what it _returns._ IMO, the difference is worth noting.

Comment: @BlacklightShining By definition, no shell script or shell command returns anything other than a numeric exit status between 0 - 255. That's axiomatic, but not generally not what people mean when they ask these types of questions. YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

`pwd` returns 0 unless its current working directory cannot be opened.

```
mkdir /tmp/d; cd "$_"
pwd && pwd -P; echo "$?"
rmdir ../d
pwd && pwd -P; echo "$?"
```

---

```
/tmp/d
/tmp/d
0
/tmp/d
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
1
```

Comment: `pwd` prints a directory to the command line. I believe that that is what the OP is asking about, not the exit code.

Answer (score 3):

There is this concept called `cwd` that every running process keeps track of.

Or better worded: the kernel keeps an idea of the `cwd` of each process.

That [could be read with](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94357/79743) (for a system with /proc):

```
readlink /proc/$PID_of_PROCESS/cwd
```

And for the running shell (of which its PID should be $$):

```
$ readlink /proc/$$/cwd
```

The shell keeps track of the same information (even if sometimes they might get out of sync) in the variable $PWD, and in the command `pwd`:

```
$ cd /tmp; echo "Present working directory: $PWD"
Present working directory: /tmp
$ cd /tmp; echo "Current working directory: $(pwd)"
Current working directory: /tmp
```

So, the `pwd` command presents the `cwd` of each process:

> ```
> The place each process stands inside the directory tree.
> ```

Each time a shell, script or process execute a `cd`, all those variables get updated (except some corner cases).

A shell could change its `pwd` by executing a `cd /tmp` for example.

An script could tell the shell under which it is running to change the `pwd` with a `cd /tmp` as well.

Or some other `c` process might call the kernel to execute an equivalent of a `cd /tmp`.

In all cases, the kernel `cwd` and (if the process is a shell) the shell's `pwd` gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

It returns directory from where it is called/run from & not where the script is !

Here is try.sh :

```
echo "The current working directory: $PWD"
```

This output will make more clear :

```
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh try.sh
The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh try/try.sh
The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh ./try.sh
The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh ./try/try.sh
The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ cd try
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI try]$ sh ./try.sh
The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe/try
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI try]$ sh ../try.sh
The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe/try
```

Comment: If the answer was yes the second output would refer to `/mnt/home/akarpe/try`. It is not a good idea to try to prove this by calling a shell script from the directory that contains the script. That fucks with the mind. :)

Comment: This output will make more clear :
[akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh try.sh
    The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
    [akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh try/try.sh
    The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
    [akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh ./try.sh
    The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe
    [akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ sh ./try/try.sh
    The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe

Comment: [akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI ~]$ cd try
    [akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI try]$ sh ./try.sh
    The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe/try
    [akarpe@ADM-PROD-OMNI try]$ sh ../try.sh
    The current working directory: /mnt/home/akarpe/try

Comment: @mkdrive2 Let me update my answer ! Thanks