# Bash script did not change the directory as written

Tags: shell-script

Here is my script to change the directory

```
[user@linux ~]$ cat script.sh
echo Before: $(pwd)
cd "$1"
echo After : $(pwd)
[user@linux ~]$
```

When I tested it, it did not really change the directory as shown in the last `pwd` command.

**Manual `pwd` command**

```
[user@linux ~]$ pwd
/home/user
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Test 1**

```
[user@linux ~]$ script.sh dir01/
Before: /home/user
After : /home/user/dir01
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Test 2**

```
[user@linux ~]$ script.sh /home/user/dir01
Before: /home/user
After : /home/user/dir01
[user@linux ~]$
```

**Manual `pwd` command again after that**

```
[user@linux ~]$ pwd
/home/user
[user@linux ~]$
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261672/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is launched in a new non-interactive shell that is forked from your current shell (interactive). Any changes made on the new spawned shell are reflected *only* for the lifetime of the script. So in your case, the `cd` to the new path is reflected *only* in the new shell and will be *not* be reflected back to the parent shell because the spawned shell exits when your script terminates.

You can run your script in the same shell as the one you are launching the script from using the built-in `source` command (in `bash`) or POSIX-ly using `.` command when the script is made executable. Try doing

```
. script.sh
```

or in bourne again shell `bash`, using `source`

```
source script.sh
```