# How to determine which script is being executed by bash?

Tags: ps

How would I determine which script is being executed by a process? When I use:

```
ps -u user
```

I get the following output:

```
10005194 26932  0.0  0.0 112700  1544 ?        Ss   Jun03   0:00 -bash
10005194 27117  0.0  0.0 112700  1528 ?        Ss   Apr24   0:00 -bash
10005194 27164  0.0  0.0 112700  2040 ?        Ss   Jun06   0:00 -bash
10005194 27404  0.0  0.0 112700  1544 ?        Ss   May27   0:00 -bash
10005194 27484  0.0  0.0 112700  1528 ?        Ss   Apr23   0:00 -bash
10005194 27531  0.0  0.0 112700  1528 ?        Ss   May22   0:00 -bash
...
```

There are hundreds of lines. I know that there are a number of scripts that this user is executing, but I would like to narrow down which of the scripts is holding onto threads. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `top`?

Comment: yes, but I don't see the pids held by that user. A lot of those bash scripts have finished executing, but the developer has forgotten to exit them, so they remain open threads.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I do see the processes, but the command still says only `bash`.

Comment: You can use `pstree user | grep bash` to see if bash is running something or just an active shell.

Comment: Do your scripts start with "#!/usr/bin/env bash"?

Comment: @HeshamAhmed, `pstree` becomes useless when piped to `grep`.

Comment: @Wildcard how is `-sshd-+-sshd---bash---ping` useless in finding out what bash is doing?

Comment: *A lot of those bash scripts have finished executing, but the developer has forgotten to exit them, so they remain open threads.* This isn't how scripts work. A script exits when it has no more instructions to perform. You can't forget to tell it to exit. Those are interactive shells, note the leading `-`. Also a shell will automatically exit once the thing connected to its STDIN goes away, so something is still holding them open (tmux/screen?). Have you tried running `w` (which will show you TTYs, and how long they've been idle for)?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Yes, the scripts start with #!/usr/bin/env bash

Comment: this is one of the known problems with using `#!/usr/bin/env`.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238470/7696

Comment: @Patrick, when I add `exit 0` to the end of one of the scripts, it seemed to stop new ones from accumulated. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `w` (for "wide") option.

From `man ps` (search for `wide`):

> `w`      Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.

e.g. `ps ww -u cas`:

```
$ ps ww -U cas | grep bash
 1350 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
18345 pts/34   S      0:00 /bin/bash /home/cas/bin/myscript.sh
21293 pts/34   Ss+    0:00 bash
```

The `-bash` is a login shell.

The plain `bash` is a non-login interactive shell - the tty `pts/34` is the same so you can tell that it is the parent shell (or distant grand-parent) of the `myscript.sh` bash shell.

> Using /usr/env/bin bash prevents you from determining which script is running. Instead you should specify exactly were the bash executable is for the machine you're running on.

Comment: thanks for the input, but after trying `ps ww -u <user>` it still returned only the  `-bash`.

Comment: In that case, there weren't any bash scripts running **at the time you ran the `ps`**.   Are you sure the scripts you're looking for aren't `#!/bin/sh` scripts?  Try `ps ww -u USER | grep -E '/bin/(ba)?sh '` or even `ps ww -u USER | grep -E '/bin/[^ ]*sh '`.

Comment: No, what I meant was that the `ps ww -u` shows many processes running, but they all have the command as just `-bash`. The question asks how to find which script the bash is running.

Comment: the problem is caused by using `#!/usr/bin/env` in your scripts.  there are many good reasons for not doing that, and only one trivial convenience reason for doing so (and even that is solved easier and better with a simple script to change the #! lines as required)

Comment: or, another way of putting it is that your scripts aren't `bash` scripts, they're `/usr/bin/env` scripts which happen to run the bash interpreter.

Comment: It's so confusing. One school of thought is saying "Be portable! use `/usr/bin/env bash`" Another is saying the opposite. So if I use `/usr/bin/env`, it is impossible to determine which script is actually executed? But if I use `/bin/bash`, then I'll be able to see the script in `ps ef`? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @GoldfishGrenade, yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As @cas suggests, `ps` can show you some of the information.  Adding options can show the *command line*, which is a step in the right direction.  Given this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
date
sleep 10
done
```

the suggested `ps -ww` shows these lines for that process:

```
  9417 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
  9496 pts/5    00:00:00 sleep
```

However, `ps -fwwl -u $USER` shows this:

```
0 S tom        9417   9416  0  80   0 - 29405 -      18:08 pts/5    00:00:00 bash ./foo
0 S tom        9419   9417  0  80   0 - 28111 -      18:08 pts/5    00:00:00 sleep 10
```

because I executed `./foo`.  If I had executed "foo" from my path, of course, there would be no "./".  In either case, the actual script which is executed depends upon the value of `$PATH` as well as the current working directory (when starting the script).  For some systems with procfs (such as Linux), it is possible to get that information:

- [How to read environment variables of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process)
- [Find out current working directory of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process)

Given all of that, there is enough information (for Linux, at least) for someone to construct a script which would analyze the output of `ps` to find scripts mentioned with (or without) full pathnames.

Oddly enough, I would have expected `lsof` to provide the information, because most shells act as if they had an open file descriptor to the script (but I do not see it in a quick check).  So analyzing `ps` and the shell's environment seems the way to go for a complete solution.

Further reading:

- [ps - report a snapshot of the current processes.](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3)