# Is there a way to tell if a process is chrooted?

Tags: chroot, openbsd

I am still new to understanding `chroot`. Some packages install their own users (`_packagedaemon`) and create their own directories (`/var/package/`).

However, I cannot tell if the process is configured to run in a `chroot`, and I'm not sure where to check.

Comment: There's some initial confusion here; an *account* isn't chroot'ed, a *process* is. Can you [edit] your question to spell out your actual concern around users & chroots?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you, that helps a lot! I think now where I'm having issues in rewriting the question is that I'm evaluating a few different packages written in python or Go. A Go package seems more likely to be what I install, but I'm new to having Go on a server, and since I haven't configured everything, yet, I'm trying to determine if it runs in a `chroot`, and `rcctl ls all` lists `packagename`, though it isn't on.

Comment: `ls -l /proc/PID/root` tells you the root of process PID. I have the feeling, though, that your question is not about a running process, but a script or a binary executable that is not (yet) running. I don't think there is a general method to find out whether a program might get chrooted. It's obviously easier to analyze a script (Python) than a binary (Go).

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks. I'll get it up and running and see what happens. Note, however, this question is for OpenBSD, but the Linux command is still useful to know.

Comment: I missed the OpenBSD part. I don't know if the BSDs have /proc or something equivalent.

Comment: From `rcctl`'s man page: `ls all` will list all installed daemons, `ls on` lists enabled daemons (i.e. should be running), `ls started` lists running daemons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fstat` will indicate where a (running) process is rooted.

#### Example 1: `nginx`

`nginx`'s workers run chrooted.  You can use `pgrep` get the process' ID:

```
# pgrep -lf nginx
58845 nginx: worker process
41019 nginx: master process /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

and then use `fstat` to check which files/sockets it has open:

```
# fstat -p 58845 | grep -e MODE -e " root"
USER     CMD          PID   FD MOUNT        INUM  MODE         R/W    SZ|DV
www      nginx      58845 root /var/www        2  drwxr-xr-x     r      512
```

This line, the one with `root` in the `FD` column, indicates that the process is rooted on inode 2 (`INUM` column) of mount point `/var/www`.  You can then find out that node's name using `find`:

```
# find -x /var/www -inum 2
/var/www
```

So, in this case, `nginx`'s workers are chrooted to `/var/www`.  Note that the master process doesn't run chrooted:

```
# fstat -p 41019 | grep " root"
```

comes up empty.  The master process reads all config files and then forks chrooted workers.

#### Example 2: `nsd`

`nsd` is a bit different from `nginx`, as even the main process runs chrooted in `/var/nsd`:

```
# pgrep -lf nsd
28155 nsd: server 1
45373 nsd: main
3681 nsd: xfrd

# fstat -p 45373 | grep -e MODE -e " root"
USER     CMD          PID   FD MOUNT        INUM  MODE         R/W    SZ|DV
_nsd     nsd        45373 root /var         8580  drwxr-xr-x     r      512

# find -x /var -inum 8580
/var/nsd
```

Comment: I think OpenBSD default `httpd` might be slightly better as an example, because `fstat` output for `logger` and `server` for `root` has `MOUNT` as `/var` and (in my case) `INUM` `570240`, making it clearer why I need to run `# find -x /var -inum 570240` (output is `/var/www`).

Comment: Yes, but none of my machines are running `httpd`, so I couldn't use it as an example :) That is also why I included the `nsd` example, not only the main process is chrooted, but you also need to use `find` to get the inode. Since I have `/var/www` as a separate mount point, the first example might not make that clear enough.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that rather relevant detail. I just tested on a server with `nginx`, and it reported `/var` so I had to `find` the reported `INUM`. Another good one is `smtpd`, if you happen to run that one `pgrep` outputs a lot of different processes.